# Get Request don't gives any value back in Powerapps Custom Connector

Tags: json, get, key, office365, powerapps

I build a custom connector in PowerApss. I use two requests. One is Post it's working fine, but the other one is not working. It is a get request.

I use the following string. It don't gives any error back, but I also shows no text in the Powerapps text field:

ClearCollect(colMetadata; ForAll(Table(ParseJSON(MetadatenserviceTest.GETBYMandantId("UserAccount"; "application/json"; "application/json").key));{ a: Key }))

Maybe you can help me to solve the problem.

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: What is the response that is coming from the service? And what is being displayed in the text field (since the colMetadata is a collection, it cannot be set directly to the Text property of a label, for example)

Comment: I found ist out. You Request is wrong. It should be like that: ClearCollect(colMetadata;(MetadatenserviceTest.GETBYMandantId("UserAccount"; "application/json"; "application/json")) Then I get also values back and I can use them. BR Matthias